# Trying to insert multiple checkbox values into PHP using HTML form

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have a database which I want to insert user choices of drinks. If they choose to drink one of the drinks I want a number 1 assigned to the record.

**HTML**

```
<form role="form" action="/form.php" name="submitfkgo" id="submitfkgo" method="post" onsubmit="return submitfk()">
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="FormEmail" name="FormEmail" placeholder="Enter email">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="FormName" name="FormName" placeholder="Enter full name">
<input type="checkbox" name="checker[]" id="formOpt1" value="A">
Yes, I will drink A
<input type="checkbox" name="checker[]" id="formOpt2" value="B">
Yes, I will drink B
<input type="checkbox" name="checker[]" id="formOpt3" value="C">
Yes, I will drink C
<a href="#join" onclick="javascript:submitfk();return false" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Submit my application!</a>
</form>
```

**PHP**

The below PHP connects to the database. Then it securely stores the values into variables. Then it creates the first record. I then want to update the record with what they have ticked from the choices above. At the moment all combinations just update with 0.

```
<?php
// DB
include("../inc/c.php");
mysql_select_db("join", $con);

// VARS
$FormEmail=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['FormEmail']);
$FormName=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['FormName']);
$chkbox = array('A', 'B', 'C');
$choiceDrink=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['checker']);

// SQL
$r=mysql_query("
    INSERT INTO `db`.`join` (`id`, `FormEmail`, `FormName`) VALUES (NULL, '".$FormEmail."', '".$FormName."');
");

// GET INSERTED RECORD
$id = mysql_insert_id();

$values = array();
foreach($chkbox as $selection ){
    if(in_array($selection, $choiceDrink))
    {
        $values[ $selection ] = 1;
    } else {
        $values[ $selection ] = 0;
    }
}

// SQL FOR CHOICES
$r2=mysql_query("
    UPDATE `db`.`join`
        SET
        `A` = '".$values['A']."',
        `B` = '".$values['B']."',
        `C` = '".$values['C']."'
    WHERE
        `join`.`id` =".$id.";
");

// FORM
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location="/thanks"</script>';

// MYSQL CLOSE
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: `$_POST['checker']` is an array, `mysql_real_escape_string` only works with scalar values.

Comment: have you debugged if the arrays $values and $choiceDrink are containing desired values? have you tried putting a single quote around `id` in this line `WHERE join.id =".$id.";` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `mysql_real_escape_string` on `$_POST['checker']`. You only need that when you're substituting an input directly into the database. So it should just be:

```
$choiceDrink=$_POST['checker'];
```

Comment: This solution worked. How would I make it secure. Can you write out some code for others to benefit from

Comment: It's already secure. You're getting the field names from `$chkbox`, and the only values are `0` and `1`. Any values that the user sends that aren't in `$chkbox` will simply be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest , primarily to check the array size of `$_POST['checker']` .
Then conditionally build SQL query as

```
if(count($_POST['checker']) ==0)
{
// SQL Query

}
else if (count($_POST['checker']) ==1)
{
// SQL query
}

//...
else
{

}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<form role="form" action="/form.php" name="submitfkgo" id="submitfkgo" method="post" onsubmit="return submitfk()">
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="FormEmail" name="FormEmail" placeholder="Enter email">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="FormName" name="FormName" placeholder="Enter full name">
<input type="checkbox" name="checker" id="formOpt1" value="A">
Yes, I will drink A
<input type="checkbox" name="checker" id="formOpt2" value="B">
Yes, I will drink B
<input type="checkbox" name="checker" id="formOpt3" value="C">
Yes, I will drink C
<a href="#join" onclick="javascript:submitfk();return false" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Submit my application!</a>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
...

// VARS
$FormEmail=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['FormEmail']);
$FormName=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['FormName']);
$choiceDrink=$_POST['checker'];

// SQL
$r=mysql_query("
    INSERT INTO `db`.`join` (`id`, `FormEmail`, `FormName`) VALUES (NULL, '".$FormEmail."', '".$FormName."');
");

// GET INSERTED RECORD
$id = mysql_insert_id();

$values = array('A' => 0, 'B' => 0, 'C' => 0);
if (isset($values[$choiceDrink])) $values[ $choiceDrink ] = 1;

// SQL FOR CHOICES
$r2=mysql_query("
    UPDATE `db`.`join`
        SET
        `A` = '".$values['A']."',
        `B` = '".$values['B']."',
        `C` = '".$values['C']."'
    WHERE
        `join`.`id` =".$id.";
");

...
```